# Printing 1 to 1,000,000 in Word Form Recursively, stackoverflowexception

Tags: java, stack-overflow

First off I would like to say that this is my first post and that although I have never posted on StackOverflow.com, the people here have helped me an enormous amount and I wish I could go back and +1 all of the posts that have helped me.

That being said I was given an assignment in an algorithms class where I have to recursively convert the numbers 1 through 1,000,000 to their word counter parts.
For Example going from 1 to 1,000,000

```
one
two
three

...and so on...

one hundred and ninetyseven
one hundred and ninetyeight
one hundred and ninetynine
two hundred

...and so on...

nine hundred and ninetynine thousand nine hundred and ninetyeight
nine hundred and ninetynine thousand nine hundred and ninetynine
one million
```

I've got my code working to 8,980 just running to 10,000 for testing but then I run into a Stack Overflow. I'm not sure if the JVM puts aside only enough memory to run to 8,980 or if it's something in my code. I've written a break down of my conditionals below and pasted the code in full underneath.

```java
public class Numbers {

        private final String HUNDRED = " hundred ";
        private final String THOUSAND = " thousand ";

        private String[] zeroToNineteen = { "", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
        private String[] twentyToOneHundred = { "", "", "twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };
```

The following recursive method is my only method in my numbers class.

```java
   public void toOneMillion(int n) {
            String number = Integer.toString(n);
            String newNumber = "";
```

I first set a String `number` to the parameter `n` by means of `Integer.toString(n)`.
Then with each conditional statement I figure out the first number in the sequence and from there use that number to set a String `newNumber` to the index value in the correct array.

```java
newNumber = zeroToNineteen[Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, 1))] + THOUSAND;
```

Afterward I print `newNumber` to the console and then drop the first number from `number` and let it drop down to the next conditional.

```java
System.out.print(newNumber);
number = number.substring(1, 4);
```

I then repeat this step until the number falls between 0 and 100. Where I then println the number to the console and make the recursive call `toOneMillion(n+1);` until `n` is equal to 10,000 (for testing purposes).

I guess my question is, is it possible to achieve 1 to 1,000,000 without encountering a stackoverflow? Also if you see something in my code that shouldn't be there or code that could be written in a more efficient way (I know the whole thing could be written in a more efficient way, I'm just wondering about smaller things) could you point it out and perhaps explain? Thank you so much for reading this far, and thank you for any help to come.

### Code In Full

I have a main class that creates an instance of the numbers class and calls the recursive meathod via - `numbers.toOneMillion(1)`... and that's the only other class in my project folder, so it's this is the class with the problem.

```java
public class Numbers {
    private final String HUNDRED = " hundred ";
    private final String THOUSAND = " thousand ";

    private String[] zeroToNineteen = { "", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve",
            "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
    private String[] twentyToOneHundred = { "", "", "twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

    public void toOneMillion(int n) {
        String number = Integer.toString(n);
        String newNumber = "";

        if (n == 10000) {
            System.out.println("10000");
        } else if (n > 0) {
            if (n >= 100) {
                if (n >= 1000) {
                    if (n % 1000 == 0) {
                        newNumber = zeroToNineteen[Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, 1))] + THOUSAND;
                        System.out.print(newNumber);
                        number = number.substring(1, 4);
                    } else {
                        newNumber = zeroToNineteen[Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, 1))] + THOUSAND;
                        System.out.print(newNumber);
                        number = number.substring(1, 4);
                        // System.out.println("HELLO!" + number + " " + n);

                    }
                }

                if (Integer.parseInt(number) != 0) {
                    if (n % 100 == 0) {
                        if(zeroToNineteen[Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, 1))].equals("")) {
                            newNumber = zeroToNineteen[Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, 1))];
                            System.out.print(newNumber);
                            number = number.substring(1, 3);
                        } else {
                            newNumber = zeroToNineteen[Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, 1))] + HUNDRED;
                            System.out.print(newNumber);
                            number = number.substring(1, 3);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(zeroToNineteen[Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, 1))].equals("")) {
                            newNumber = zeroToNineteen[Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, 1))] + "and ";
                            System.out.print(newNumber);
                            number = number.substring(1, 3);
                        } else {
                            newNumber = zeroToNineteen[Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, 1))] + HUNDRED + "and ";
                            System.out.print(newNumber);
                            number = number.substring(1, 3);
                        }
                        // System.out.println("HELLO!" + number + " " + n);

                    }
                }
            }
            if (Integer.parseInt(number) < 20) {
                System.out.println(zeroToNineteen[Integer.parseInt(number)]);
                toOneMillion(n + 1);
            } else {
                if (n % 10 == 0) {
                    number = number.substring(0, 1);
                    newNumber = twentyToOneHundred[Integer.parseInt(number)];
                    System.out.println(newNumber);
                    toOneMillion(n + 1);
                } else {
                    newNumber = twentyToOneHundred[Integer.parseInt(number
                            .substring(0, 1))];
                    newNumber += zeroToNineteen[Integer.parseInt(number
                            .substring(1))];
                    System.out.println(newNumber);
                    toOneMillion(n + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I realize my code is jumbled and I should break down all of my conditionals into one method that handles the same thing for each conditional, I would just like to get the code working first and then perfect it. Also I'm almost posotive there is a much more efficient way to do what I'm trying to do, however my brain and thought processing came up with this so don't hate to hard.

Comment: 1 to 1,000,000 recursively -> stackoverflow... hmm... (Hint: think of what a recursion does to the stack)

Comment: I suspect the aim of the exercise is not to nest 1000000 recursive calls (because that's just silly), but rather to do something like one level of recursion per digit position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a feeling you are misunderstanding where they are expecting the recursion.

Thinking more along the lines of :

```
for(int i=0; i<100000; i++){
   printNumberRecursively(i);
}
```

Where `printNumberRecursively` runs through the number recursively one digit at a time.

If I'm wrong then the assignment is ludicrous.

Comment: I never even thought of that, I just wasted so much time. Would this code be placed in my Numbers class or in the class that creates an instance of the Numbers class?

Comment: Make it a helper function inside the Numbers class I think. Also you may want to rename the `toOneMillion` function.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do `toOneMillion(n + 1)`. This add information to the stack at each recursive call. Instead, you should call `toOneMillion` inside a `for` loop.